# Openlayers 3 - click under geolocation layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers, layers, geolocation, z-index

I am using geolocation feature of Openlayers 3.13, as in the examples. (http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.0/examples/geolocation.html)

However I also have queryable point layers, and when I track the position, I cannot click under the "accuracy feature".

Do you know any way of avoiding this problem?

The best would be to not detect any feature at all for the accuracy (even not change the cursor).

I tried z index and render order, but they did not work.

I ended up removing accuracy, but I would like to find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `ol.Map#forEachFeatureAtPixel` for detecting clicks, you can set the optional `layerFilter`:

```
map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature) {
  // do something with detected features
}, undefined, function(layer) {
  return layer !== geolocationLayer;
});
```

In the above snippet, `geolocationLayer` is the vector layer from the example you linked.